# The Attribute of "ref" for XML Schema For C# Parse

Tags: c#, xml

Good day.

I got a problem about the attribute of "ref" for my XSD file.
My code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;


class XmlSchemaTraverseExample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Add the customer schema to a new XmlSchemaSet and compile it.
        // Any schema validation warnings and errors encountered reading or 
        // compiling the schema are handled by the ValidationEventHandler delegate.
        XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemaSet.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallback);
        schemaSet.Add("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "recipe.xsd");
        schemaSet.Compile();

        // Retrieve the compiled XmlSchema object from the XmlSchemaSet
        // by iterating over the Schemas property.
        XmlSchema customerSchema = null;
        foreach (XmlSchema schema in schemaSet.Schemas())
        {
            customerSchema = schema;
        }

        // Iterate over each XmlSchemaElement in the Values collection
        // of the Elements property.
        foreach (XmlSchemaElement element in customerSchema.Elements.Values)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Element: {0}", element.Name);

            // Get the complex type of the Customer element.
            XmlSchemaComplexType complexType = element.ElementSchemaType as XmlSchemaComplexType;

            // If the complex type has any attributes, get an enumerator 
            // and write each attribute name to the console.
            if (complexType.AttributeUses.Count > 0)
            {
                IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator =
                    complexType.AttributeUses.GetEnumerator();

                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    XmlSchemaAttribute attribute =
                        (XmlSchemaAttribute)enumerator.Value;

                    Console.WriteLine("Attribute: {0}", attribute.Name);
                }
            }

            // Get the sequence particle of the complex type.
            XmlSchemaSequence sequence = complexType.ContentTypeParticle as XmlSchemaSequence;

            // Iterate over each XmlSchemaElement in the Items collection.
            foreach (XmlSchemaElement childElement in sequence.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Element: {0}, {1}, {2}", childElement.RefName, childElement.MinOccurs, childElement.MaxOccurs);
            }
        }
    }

    static void ValidationCallback(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
            Console.Write("WARNING: ");
        else if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
            Console.Write("ERROR: ");

        Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
    }
}
```

my XSD file

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="Recipe">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="DocumentInfo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <!-- Element of DocumentInfo -->
  <xsd:element name="DocumentInfo">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:attribute name="Description" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:attribute name="Creator" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:attribute name="CreateTime" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:attribute name="Revisor" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:attribute name="ReviseTime" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:attribute name="Version" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:attribute name="Frozen" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:attribute name="ASCSVersion" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Now when i got the output below:

```
Element: Recipe
Element: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:DocumentInfo, 1, 1
Element: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:Prerequisite, 1, 1
Element: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:Headers, 0, 1
Element: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:Steps, 1, 1
```

How to remove the prefix of "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ?
I can only take use of the Attribute of "childElement.RefName", I can't find "childElement.Ref".

DEV IDE: VS2005. .NET 2.0.

Thanks in advance here.

BR!
Nano

Comment: You'll get more traffic if you tag your question with the language your code is written in.

Comment: I inserted the C# tag for my question.

Thank you Paul.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `childElement.Name` or `childElement.QualifiedName.Name`

[XmlSchemaElement.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaelement.name.aspx)

[XmlSchemaElement.QualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaelement.qualifiedname.aspx)

Comment: Hello Zach,

childElement.QualifiedName.Name worked now.

Thanks a lot.

Nano.